# Efficiently appending or inserting a variable number of spaces to a string

Tags: c++, string, insert, append

I have a simple programme that inserts or appends a number of spaces to align text.

```
f()
{
    string word = “This word”;
    const string space = “ “;
    int space_num = 5; // this number can vary 
    for (int i = 0; i < space_num; i++)
        {
            word.insert(0, space);
        }   
    cout << word;
}
```

Now this works, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this. Not in terms of optimizing my programme, but more as in standard practice.

I can imagine two potential methods:

1 - Is there a way to create a string of say 20 spaces, and append a portion of those spaces rather than repeatedly adding a single space.

2 – Is there a way to create string with a variable number of spaces and append that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, both take a number of copies and a character:

```
word.insert(0, space_num, ' ');
word.append(space_num, ' ');
```

For aligning text, keep in mind you can use a string stream and the `<iomanip>` header, such as `std::setw` as well.

Comment: Both your and taocp's answers are great. I think this answer provides more with regards to the aligning information as well as being very clear and concise. I'll run an effiency test (if I can) to see which is faster before awarding the best answer. Thank you both for your quick and clear answers.

Comment: I need a better speed test programme, I guess that's my next project. I think this method came out faster. I'd rather have concrete results than the awful ones I got.

Comment: @David, Are you sure that this, of all the code in your project, is the slow part?

Comment: I wasn't really worried about it being slow in this case. I was just looking at a better way to do it. My route seemed a little unwieldy.

Answer (score 2):

> 1 - Is there a way to create a string of say 20 spaces, and append a portion of those spaces rather than repeatedly adding a single space.

Yes, try this:

```
 string spaces(20, ' ');
 string portionOfSpaces = spaces.substr(0,10); //first 10 spaces
 string newString = portionOfSpaces + word;
```

Generally, you can use `substr` to get a portion of spaces and do operations with that substring.

> 2 – Is there a way to create string with a variable number of spaces and append that?

Yes, see string constructor:`string (size_t n, char c);` and [string::append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)

Comment: Why would you create `spaces` with 20 characters just to extract the first 10 with `substr`? Just create the number of spaces you need in the first place!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I did that as OP asked for it if I understood correctly. But I agree with you that we only need to create the number of spaces needed.

Comment: Creating 20 would mean the same space string could be reused for formatting multiple strings rather than making a string of spaces for each. Whether it is quicker - I don't know.

Comment: @David: Not really, as the `substr` will create a copy of the string. Obtaining the `substr` is as expensive as creating the correct string in the first place.